# How to use Angular to call SAS STP service?

Tags: sas

I am trying to make an Angular web app to call SAS STP service. I have tested the page to make a 'GET' request from 'http://date.jsontest.com' and it worked perfectly. However, when I switched the URL to SAS STP service (https://server:port/SASStoredProcess/do1?_program=/Shared+Data/stp_service) it kept giving me an error saying I am not allowed.

I have tested the SAS STP service with Postman and was able to get a return successfully. do I need to deploy the STP service as Web service?

Comment: this has been incorrectly flagged as a duplicate

Comment: what is the exact error you receive from the SAS service?  Have you deployed with streaming output?  Your URL looks funny as well (`do1?` vs `do?`)

Comment: Take a look at this library for calling SAS services, there is also an angular seed app:  https://github.com/Boemska/h54s

Comment: are you working locally or are your files being sent from the SAS Web Server?  If local then CORS will be an issue.  See: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/1091-2017.pdf and the links at the bottom of this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-tips-sas-app-developers-allan-bowe/

Comment: @AllanBowe I am getting this error message: `https://server:port/SASStoredProcess/do1?_program=/Shared+Data/stp_service 403 (Forbidden)`. I have setted up the CORS on the server and using the Chrome plug in.

Comment: can you access  `https://server:port/SASLogon` with your credentials?  You might want to look at the logon handling in our seed app: https://github.com/Boemska/h54s-angular-seed-app

Comment: @AllanBowe I can login to `https://server:port/SASLogon` using my credentials. I do believe the login is the issue causing the error, it seems like it is not passing in on the POST request. I will take a look at your application and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: Just a update on how we resolved this issue.

We made added the web server domain and port number in `SASMC -> Plug-Ins -> Application Management -> Configuration Manager -> Properties -> Advanced -> referrers.knownHosts `

Comment: thanks for sharing!

Comment: This question should be re-opened.  The issue was unrelated to CORS.  I've removed the angularjs and nodejs tags.